# Redirection after alert() does not working

Tags: javascript, animation

I have the following function,

```
Render: function (level, cpi, t1)
{
    //...
        if ((level.t0.value -= (t1 - this.t0) / 1000) <= 0) {
            alert("Game over!");

            window.location.href = "levels.php";
        }
    //...
}
```

which is called a lot by

```
(function frame ()
{
    //...
        Level.Render(level, cpi, Date.now());
    //...
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
})();
```

If the second statement becomes true, the dialog show up and if I click on "OK", it shows up again, and again, and again... no redirection, why?

Comment: `x -= y <= z?` Don't write ambiguous code, especially if you plan on having others maintain this.

Comment: @MarcB is right, x-=y <= Z  --> x-=y will not give a number
Delete your equals...
if it not works after that, use php function header("Location: url").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript code executes in a single thread and the browser doesn't start reloading the page (based on the new URL) until your JS finishes executing (e.g. responding to an event, etc.)

To make things worse, different browsers behave differently.  For example, next time you open an `alert()` in Firefox after changing `windows.location`, the browser will pickup the change and reload the page (and automatically close the alert() box).  Chrome, on the other hand, won't immediatelly pickup the location change when it executes `alert()`.

**TL;DR**: Don't try to use a window.location assignment as a global "exit" function.  If you need to break out of your code immediately, you can **throw an error** after changing the location:

```
Render: function (level, cpi, t1)
{
    //...
        if ((level.t0.value -= (t1 - this.t0) / 1000) <= 0) {
            alert("Game over!");

            window.location.href = "levels.php";
            throw("Done");
        }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the error:

Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Does this work for you?

```
level.t0.value -= (t1 - this.t0) / 1000;
if (level.t0.value <= 0) {
    alert("Game over!");
    window.location.href = "levels.php";
}
```